# How to get Searchbar toggle show/hide Scope Bar based on IBAction Value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

How to get Searchbar value and Scope Bar Value to a variable 
so i can be able to send it as a GET value to a REST API like

searchTerm
rateType

I have the following code.

```
- (IBAction)showSearchOptions:(id)sender {    
    if(toggle == 0){
        [self.searchBar sizeToFit];
        self.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"High Rate", @"Low Rate", nil];
        self.searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
        [self.searchBar sizeToFit];
        toggle = 1;

    } else {

        self.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = nil;
        [self.searchBar sizeToFit];
        toggle = 0;
    }

  }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `UISearchBar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer to this is the following: Can you please correct if the declaration of the Integer is properly? based on Coding Standards. This works but i want always to get better. thanks. I saw the Documentation

Documentation Scope Bar: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference.html

SearchBar Delegate: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
NSString *searchTerm = searchBar.text;
int rateLevel = searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex;

NSString *rateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Your Search Term is '%@' and Your Rate Type is '%d'", searchTerm, rateLevel];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"hey!" 
message:rateString 
delegate:self 
cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
otherButtonTitles:@"Try Again",nil];

[alert show];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need something like  `self.searchbar.text` and it's ussually made for filter with `NSPredicate`

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{    
    NSPredicate *predi = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tags CONTAINS[c] %@", self.searchBar.text];
}
```

Comment: I just need to grab the values so i can make a HTTP Request to an API so i can get a JSON response and repopulate the TableView. Based on 2 values Subject + Rate

Comment: using self.searchbar.text i get a error that says not found object type. But when used without the self works fine.

Comment: it depends where are you calling it, i supposed that is a UIView interface or some child..., if this is usefull you are free to mark as answered : )

Comment: it depends too if, you are linking the searchbar with the code using the storyboar, (you should do this) if you don't know what i'm talking about i can give u a link of the tuttorial

Comment: @FelipeQuirós Why would you use `self.searchBar` in a method that has `searchBar` as a parameter? Just reference the `searchBar` parameter.

Comment: cause searchBar normally is linked (as i told you) from the story board to your .h class file, this is useful cause u have the actual reference of the object always, on any part of the code... just the way you want.

Comment: In my case, i just need it cause i use that variable on several methods, and it's a pretty well way to standard the use of that source of info, on one variable :) do it if u want, use the local one if you don't mind it.